# Asynchronous execution of sql using unixODBC api is failing

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, unixodbc

I wanted to lock a table from one application and insert some data. And my requirement is, if that table is already locked by anyother process then I need to try to lock after a specific amount of time.

I am using unixODBC driver in centOS machine and my database is postgresql. I did a research on how to execute a sql asynchronously using odbc api. I found SQLSetStmtAttr api can be used to execute the sql statement asynchronously. But its not working.

This is how I wrote the code :

```
 ret =  SQLSetStmtAttr( stmt1,  SQL_ATTR_ASYNC_ENABLE,(SQLPOINTER) SQL_ASYNC_ENABLE_ON, 0);
// above statement returned success

 if((ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt1,"lock table test",SQL_NTS)) == SQL_STILL_EXECUTING)
  {
     printf("\nCanceling\n");
     ret = SQLCancel(stmt);
  }
```

//But process is getting hang on SQLExecDirect api, as that table "test" is already locked by another process. (Hang in the sense, waiting for all other processes to release the  lock)

Why is it so ? Is that because my unixODBC driver does not support asynchronous execution. if its so why SQLSetStmtAttr is returning success ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using freeTDS driver? You have mentioned unixODBC, i think its a Driver Manager and not a driver itself.

I was looking at freeTDS ODBC driver code.

It looks like even though SQLSetStmtAttr() does the job of setting SQL_ASYNC_ENABLE_ON, functions that actually utilize this attribute are using hard-coded value  SQL_ASYNC_ENABLE_OFF.